# how to fetch data from table based on date range(last day, last week, last month,last year) in a single query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table called sales which is displayed below:

```
s.no        item_sold       date

1           soap            25.07.2017

2           bisket          19.07.2017

3           chocklate       26.06.2017

4           milk            26.06.2016
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I am not getting any clue, I only tried separately.

Answer (score 1):

Use subdate(current_date, 1)
and BETWEEN.

Eg. To get records between yesterday and day before yesterday. 
You can do something like this:

```
SELECT .. FROM ... WHERE your_date_column BETWEEN 
subdate(current_date, 1) AND subdate(current_date, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Uh... I guess...

```
select * from sales where date between '2017-06-01' and '2017-07-31'
```

But I think your field name "date" and "s.no" are going to cause you problems...